# Detect screen width for multiple monitors

Tags: javascript, screen-resolution

My website is optimized (with fixed width) for 1024x768 layout. I plan to add vertical banners on either side of the page for people having resolution width 1280 or higher.

Using screen.width, I can easily do this. But I face a problem when trying it on machines with multiple monitors.

**Lets assume the below mentioned scenario:**
 
Monitor 1 (primary display) - Resolution is 1024 x 768
 
Monitor 2 (secondary display) - Resolution is 1440 x 900

screen.width always shows width as 1024 irrespective of the monitor I browse the page on. The values are reversed if I change the primary monitor to Monitor 2.

This is a big problem especially for people having 1024x768 resolution as primary resolution. This means that I could potentially loose banner impressions in such scenarios.

I would really appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for your response duskwuff. Helped me compile the below function which solved the problem for me.

```
function getBrowserWith()
{
    if(($.browser.msie == true && $.browser.version == '9.0') || $.browser.webkit == true || $.browser.mozilla == true)
        return window.innerWidth;
    else if(($.browser.msie == true) && ($.browser.version == '7.0' || $.browser.version == '8.0'))
        return document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    else
        return screen.width;
}
```

**Important notes**

1. jQuery 1.4+ is required
2. Note that the above function has been tested only for IE7+, FF7+ & Chrome16+ browsers.

Comment: Won't work if user is not using browser on fullscreen.

Comment: This does not give the monitors/screens width or height. It only gives the window width or window height!

Comment: $.browser.msie has been removed in jquery 1.9

Answer (score 7):

Try looking at `window.innerWidth` (the width of the web page on screen) instead of `window.screen.width`.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/23365665/4954580 for dual monitor