# is there any way to know extends screen in javascript

Tags: javascript

is there any way to know extends screen in javascript?

by `screen.availWidth` and `screen.availHeight` you can only know the width and height just for the main screen

Comment: What do you mean by extending the screen ? Resizing the window

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to how to detect extended screens (on two monitors), and your browser window is going on both screens, you can detect with the following code:

```
var extendedScreen = ( window.innerWidth > screen.availWidth );
```

But the code above won't work if the browser width is less than the available width of the screen. I don't know of a generic method to detect.

Have a look also to https://stackoverflow.com/a/9788029/279262 for a cross-browser function that detects the screen width.

Comment: Seems not to be a correct solution. If you zoom-out in Chrome then innerWith is more then availWidth (on 1 screen)